# Searching by sea on a distant planet for a drug found in whale-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been unsuccessfully trying to find a short story about a group of people that travel by boat on a distant planet.  This group is led by a captain and a drug addict/dealer  who is searching for an illegal drug that (I think) is only in some type of whale-like/man-of-war type creature on this planet.

I believe that this was a short story collection from the 1980s, maybe a hallucinogenic drug. Not sure if crew native to the planet, but I know the crew perishes.  I originally thought it was Involution Ocean by Bruce Sterling but I was wrong.  Thanks again for all the help and responses.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange.  You’ve provided a good amount of information about this story.  Do you remember whether you read it in a hardcover or paperback collection of short stories, or was it in a newsstand magazine such as *Analog* or *Asimov’s*?  Do you remember anything about the cover?  about the author?  (Well known or unknown?  Male or female?)  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.  You may be interested in checking out [our guidance](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on writing a good story-ID question.

Comment: What does the drug do? Cure cancer? Reverse aging? Grow hair? Hallucinogenic? Euphoric? Aphrodisiac? Hypnotic?

Comment: Are the boat people native to the planet, or did they travel to the planet from earth or somewhere else in space to hunt the drug-producing whales?

Comment: I don't think this is it, enough I'm not sure of or doesn't quite match that I don't feel confident putting it as a full answer, but possibly one of the stories in the shared world anthology Murasaki?  At least one of the stories does involve a sea trip and hunting of "carpet whales", giant sea creatures that might be intelligent (although I can't remember if for food or drugs and I think the human captain was trying to stop the natives from hunting)

Comment: Frogheads by Allen M Steele? Included in Old Venus edited by George RR Martin and Gardner Dozois. This was quite a recent compilation, I think 2015 so maybe not what you are looking for.